# Terraform replace function doesn't work in conditional

Tags: terraform

I have a code which checks if key in the loop has word Ops and if yes then assigns value to provider either aws.peer or aws.default.

```
provider = "${replace(each.key, "Ops", "") != each.key ? "aws.peer" : "aws.default"}"
```

After I run it it returns:

```
Error: Invalid provider reference

On ../../modules/Stack/Peering/main.tf line 13: Provider argument requires a provider name followed by an optional alias, like "aws.foo".
```

Not sure why

Comment: Can you add more of your code to the same?  At a minimum, I'd like to see the resource you are creating where you are trying to set the provider reference.

Comment: And the aws providers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Provider selection is not allowed to be dynamic in Terraform. If you share more of your script, we might be able to give you a workaround that is specific to the solution you are building.

> Provider selections cannot be dynamic like this. Although it didn’t produce an error in Terraform 0.11, it also didn’t work: Terraform 0.11 just ignored it and treated it as a literal string, just as the terraform 0.12upgrade tool showed. Terraform 0.12 has an explicit validation check for it to give you better feedback that it’s not supported.

The connections between resources and their providers happens too early for Terraform to be able to evaluate expressions in that context, because the provider must be known in order to understand the other contents of the block.

Resource w/ possible work around:
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/defining-provider-aliases-with-string-interpolation-not-working-in-terraform-0-12/1569/4